# @WebServlet in Weblogic server

Tags: java, weblogic

I am using `@WebServlet("/servletname")` in my apache server and it is working fine. I moved my application to weblogic server and it is not working. It say *404 for the /servletname*. Please help me to identify the issue.

Comment: Please add more information about the issue you are experiencing, to avoid the thread being closed before your get your answer. An apache access log of the 404 may be helpful too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use something like:

```
@WLServlet (name = "servletname", mapping = {"/servletname"})
```

and you have to import this statement

`weblogic.servlet.annotation.WLServlet;`

You may get error for above statement, for that you have to add below external Jar which you will find

> $WL_HOME/modules/com.bea.core.weblogic.web.api_1.4.0.0.jar

Comment: Thanks. Any chance to make it work with the Java Servlet API instead of Weblogic libraries?

Comment: WebLogic is trash.  This DID NOT work for me, the only thing that worked was to remove my @WebServlet annotation and to move the Servlet mappings back into the Web.xml.